# Enable/Disable all controllers of spring boot app?

Tags: java, spring-boot, feature-flags

I'm wondering if there is any pattern or implementation that allows me to enable/disable all the controllers **at once** of a given spring boot application by using a simple boolean variable that was provided by another feature flags service.

I'm thinking of putting a conditional check in each of the controller paths but it's a really bad way of doing it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define custom Filter and register that. Sample Filter code at.

```
public class RequestAllowDenyFilter implements Filter {

    private boolean isAllowed = true;

    public RequestAllowDenyFilter(boolean isAllowed) {
        this.isAllowed = isAllowed;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (isAllowed) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            ((HttpServletResponse) response).setStatus(HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE.value());
        }
    }

}
```

Then when you register filter you need to pass do you want to allow/deny request.

```
@Value("${request.enabled:true}")
private boolean isEnabled;

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean<RequestAllowDenyFilter> loggingFilter() {
    FilterRegistrationBean<RequestAllowDenyFilter> registrationBean
      = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();

    registrationBean.setFilter(new RequestAllowDenyFilter(isEnabled));
    registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/**");
    registrationBean.setOrder(0);

    return registrationBean;
}
```

You need to define `request.enabled` in application.properties file. Either true/false based on what you want to do.